# Failed to send email: no recipient (line 19, file "Email")

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I got notification like this

> Exception: Failed to send email: no recipient (line 19, file "Email")

I got no idea what happened

```
/**
 * Sends emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 3; // First row of data to process
  var getLastRow = 900; // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, getLastRow, 6);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var trigger = row[0]; // kolom ke 1 TRIGGER
    var emailAddress = row[2]; // Email column
    var message = row[4]; // Content column
    var subject = row[3]; // Subject Column
    var status_email = row[5];
    if ((trigger != 'FALSE') && (status_email != 'EMAIL_SENT')) { // Prevents sending duplicates
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 6).setValue('EMAIL_SENT');
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Os emails estão estão em qual coluna?

Comment: @SidneyCardosodosSantos Please write in English.

Comment: Welcome to [so] Please add more details like sample data input and the corresponding expected result. Note: Is very likely that the Email column has some blank cells.

Comment: hi ruben, 

thanks for your response...alright this is my sample data link :

_[link] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NFM4rjNngse-i4kCwhvcCfeeXb8GctJXrb9zfgXlLiE/edit?usp=sharing)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You define `getLastRow = 900` and `emailAddress = row[2]`

- This means that from row 3 to row 900 you expect an email address to be present in each cell of column C
- If you try to send an email from a row that does not contain an email address wou will get the error you metnioned

### How to avoid the error?

Catch it with an `if` statement that checks either the cell is empty before sending the email

**Sample**

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 3; // First row of data to process
  var getLastRow = 900; // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, getLastRow, 6);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var trigger = row[0]; // kolom ke 1 TRIGGER
    var emailAddress = row[2]; // Email column
    if(emailAddress != "" && emailAddress != " "){ 
      var message = row[4]; // Content column
      var subject = row[3]; // Subject Column
      var status_email = row[5];
      if ((trigger != 'FALSE') && (status_email != 'EMAIL_SENT')) { // Prevents sending duplicates
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
        sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 6).setValue('EMAIL_SENT');
        // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }
    }
  }
}
```